# Show if ItemsControl.ItemsSource is null

Tags: c#, silverlight, xaml, binding, itemssource

Greetings,

I have a ItemsControl which template I changed to show a RadioButton for every object in the binded ItemsSource.

However the ItemsSource can be empty and when it is empty I'd like to show a default value. Something like "The binded list contains no items for you to select"...

One way I thought of is to set the ItemsControl.Visibility to Collapsed and have a TextBlock.Vsibility to Visible which shows the text.. But this would include a lot more data.

Is it possible to show a default value if the ItemsControl.ItemsSource is null?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood correctly, I think you can solve your problem by creating an `IValueConverter`.

Comment: Since the ItemsControl shows a radiobutton as ItemTemplate, nomather how I implement a IValueConverter, it won't change the ItemTemplate (As far as I know).

Comment: Created a Converter which shows me wether my List is empty or not. Based on that I show either the ItemsControl or a TextBlock showing there isn't any item available!

Answer (score 4):

After creating this simple converter:

```
public class AnyItemsToVisibilityConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        var collection = value as IEnumerable;
        if (collection == null)
            return Visibility.Collapsed;

        return collection.OfType<object>().Any() ? Visibility.Collapsed : Visibility.Visible;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

You can override the ItemsControl Template to suppor this using RelativeSource Binding.

```
<UserControl x:Class="SilverlightApplication1.MainPage"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:SilverlightApplication1">
    <UserControl.Resources>
        <local:AnyItemsToVisibilityConverter x:Key="AnyItemsToVisibilityConverter" />
    </UserControl.Resources>

    <Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="White">
        <ItemsControl>
            <ItemsControl.Template>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="ItemsControl">
                    <Grid>
                        <TextBlock Text="No Items to Display" 
Visibility="{Binding Items, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, Converter={StaticResource AnyItemsToVisibilityConverter}}" />
                        <ItemsPresenter />
                    </Grid>
                </ControlTemplate>     
            </ItemsControl.Template>
        </ItemsControl>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

Comment: Nice! But I would either rename `AnyItemsToVisibilityConverter`, or invert the returned value - to me `if any then visible` makes more sense. Also, thanks for the template!

Answer (score 1):

You should not create a Converter which shows  wether your List is empty or not. It is better when your XAML,Converter and data source are totally independent items. Isn't MVVM about loose coupling?

OK, code behind is evil. Thanks for pointing that out.
I corrected the source code, it is totally declarative style now:

```
       <ControlTemplate x:Key="ListBoxTemplate" TargetType="ListBox">
            <StackPanel>
            <ItemsPresenter  
                 Visibility="{Binding Path=NotEmpty,
                Converter={StaticResource BoolToVisibilityConverter}}">
            </ItemsPresenter>
                <TextBlock Text="No items to select from" 
                 Visibility="{Binding Path=Empty,
                 Converter={StaticResource BoolToVisibilityConverter}}"/>
            </StackPanel>
        </ControlTemplate>

        <Style x:Key="ListBoxStyle2" TargetType="ListBox"  >
            <Setter Property="Template" Value="{StaticResource ListBoxTemplate}">
            </Setter>
            <Setter Property="ItemsPanel">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                        <StackPanel />
                    </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
```

Comment: You do realise that Silverlight is mostly for it's MVVM structure..  and this code behind should only be used unless absolutely necassary? Thus though this method may work. It's still a bad example! Also, bad formatting and hardly understandable. Downvoting

Comment: +1 because downvotes should NOT be based on opinion. MVVM is the preferable way of working but this was still a valid answer.

Answer (score 0):

One thing you could do is that after checking `ItemsControl.ItemsSource` is null, you could add a single item `"The binded list contains no items for you to select"`. I hope this would server your purpose.

Comment: Since the ItemsControl shows a radiobutton as ItemTemplate it would show a Radiobutton with the text "The binded list contains no items for you to select". However I wish it to be a textblock