# ItemsControl DataContext Binding Error

Tags: c#, wpf, binding, converters, itemscontrol

I have already looked into this solution: [Show if ItemsControl.ItemsSource is null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5977096/show-if-itemscontrol-itemssource-is-null).
I set the DataContext of the ItemsControl via codebehind to an ObservableCollection. Everything works fine except that it only resolves once during the loading phase. If the items control has a few items in the start, the text disappears but doesn't appear later onwards. If it's empty, the text appears, but it doens't go away when i add items later on. I have tried ItemsSource as well but no luck. I'm aware im using a control template as of now, and i can use relative source TemplatedParent but i just wanted to make sure. Upon further testing, the converter function doesn't seem to activate after i try to add/remove items in the list even though the items show on my itemscontrol.

```xml
<ItemsControl x:Name="MedicationList" ItemTemplate="{StaticResource UserTemplate}">
  <ItemsControl.Template>
    <ControlTemplate TargetType="ItemsControl">
      <Grid>
        <TextBlock Text="No Items to Display" Visibility="{Binding DataContext, ElementName=MedicationList, Converter={StaticResource AnyItemsToVisibilityConverter}}" />
        <ItemsPresenter />
      </Grid>
    </ControlTemplate>     
  </ItemsControl.Template>
</ItemsControl>
```

Comment: Shouldn't you be investigating why the DataContext changes then?

Comment: I tried moving my Datacontext assignment from the UserControl_Loaded event to just under the InitializeComponent(); and the DataContext null problem went away. I put breakpoints into my converter function and it only executes once during the assignment but never when i add/remove items

Comment: In retrospect, i don't really need a converter. I'm open to any ideas. I'm thinking about DataTriggers as well, but i don't know how to implement it. Basically i just need to Collaspe the TextBlock if there are 0 items in the DataSource which is an ObservableCollection<T>

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What are you using as the datacontext/itemssource?  If it is an `ObservableCollection` as I would expect, then you would be best off binding to its "Count" property and then using a trigger to collapse the text block when necessary.

The reason that the binding isn't currently updating is that the `DataContext` itself isn't actually changing.  Properties on the `DataContext` ARE changing, so if you bind to the correct property (count) your bindings will update.

This code snippet should work:

```xml
<ControlTemplate TargetType="ItemsControl">
  <Grid>
    <TextBlock x:Name="txtBlock" Text="No Items to Display" Visibility="Collapsed" />
    <ItemsPresenter />
  </Grid>
  <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=Count}" Value="0">
      <Setter TargetName="txtBlock" Property="Visibility" Value="Visible"/>
    </DataTrigger>
  </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
</ControlTemplate>
```

By using a data trigger you can avoid the need for a converter to convert a numeric value into a visibility and keep everything in your .xaml.

Comment: Perfect! This is the exact solution i was looking for! Simple and clean. Thank you so much.